# WebRequest and HttpServletRequest in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-3

What is the difference between the two? Both have a `getParameter` method as well as `setAttribute` method, then where comes the difference between the two?

1) Which one is better to use in general?

2) Please explain specific scenarios where they can be used.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [javadoc of WebRequest](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/WebRequest.html) is pretty clear on the subject:

> Generic interface for a web request. **Mainly intended for generic web request interceptors, giving them access to general request metadata, not for actual handling of the request.**

(emphasis mine).

The javadoc links to WebRequestInterceptor, which says:

> Interface for general web request interception. Allows for being applied to Servlet request as well as Portlet request environments, by building on the WebRequest abstraction.

So, basically, you should not use WebRequest except in a WebRequestInterceptor. And they introduced this interface in order to be able to write interceptors that apply to servlets and portlets. Other than that, if you really need access to the request in Spring MVC controllers, you should use the standard HttpServletRequest.

Comment: So, your interpretation of the JavaDoc reference directly contradicts the reference documentation, where among the supported argument types for request mapping methods in a controller there is the following item: "`org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest` or `org.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest`. Allows for generic request parameter access as well as request/session attribute access, without ties to the native Servlet/Portlet API." It also explains the differences (and the advantages) of using it instead of `HttpServletRequest`.