# Get and set attributes in session - Spring framework

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-mvc

I am using Spring Framework. Well in some part of program I store an Attribute in session like this

```
req.setAttribute("learnerGroup", form.getGroup(), WebRequest.SCOPE_SESSION); // save the object/String in session
```

Where **`req`** is of type - **`WebRequest`**.

In the other part of program I have **`HttpServletRequest hreq`**.

**Questions**

**1)** Is it right way to save `Object`s is session, like I did above using `WebRequest` ?

**2)** How do I retrieve the saved `Object` from the session using `HttpServletRequest` ?

Comment: This might help you:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/24343067/259889

Comment: @Sid this isn't very helpful for me ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes, that will indeed save the object in the session attribute named `"learnerGroup"`.
2. using `request.getSession().getAttribute("learnerGroup")`

Comment: and vise versa ? i.e. to `getAttribute` from `WebRequest` object when it is set using `HttpServletRequest.setAttribute();`. Please update your answer accordingly too. Thanks

Comment: Seriously? Read the javadoc: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/WebRequest.html.

Comment: I want to say that is it right that I do like `HttpServletRequest.getSession().setAttribute("abc","abcdef");`. So can I retreive the session attribute like `WebRequest().getAttribute("abc");`. I think now its little more clear. Thanks

Comment: There is no method getAttribute() taking only a String as argument in WebRequest. Read the API doc.

Comment: There is a method named `getAttribute()` ... It is inherited from `org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestAttributes`.

Comment: And what does it take as argument?

Comment: So, given that you used setAttribute("learnerGroup", object, WebRequest.SCOPE_SESSION) to set an attribute in the session, what do you think you must pass to getAttribute() to get the attribute "learnerGroup" from the session?

Answer (score 0):

session object attributes are final, so you may not be able to update them.
But you can try this: perform `getAttribute()`, save it somewhere and `setAttribute()`.

Sessions are not subjected to change or update, they are meant to be created and invalidated.
Maybe that is the reason, we do not have update Attribute there.